# Page loading slow/structure showing, drop down not working in IE

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Two questions in regards to a website I am working on...

My website:  http://thendesign.com/new/type.html (I do not have everything loaded so I know some of my image links do not exist)

1. when the page is refreshed, the structure of my code blips before the page is loaded. I have tried combining all of my .css and .js files so it is only pulling one file, but it didn't help any. Is there anything else I can do?
2. I like the css dropdown that i have done, but it doesn't work at all in Internet Explorer. Do I need to completely ditch this concept and do something with jQuery? The jQuery I tried conflicts with the accordion image slider on the index page (click the logo in the top left to get to the index page).

Suggestions on a good jQuery dropdown or what I need to do to get my dropdown to work in IE (i know that the transparent background is a problem - can i make it so it is transparent where accepted but solid in IE??)

Thanks in advance for your assistance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the blip is that you don't hide all those elements until the "domenabled" class is added to the body by `ul2finder`. Since this is done in the `window.onload` handler, it doesn't happen until the page is rendered the first time. Instead of doing it there, put that check in inline JavaScript in the body of `type.html`. Then it will take effect BEFORE the rest of the body is rendered.

UPDATE: Right after the `<body>` tag, add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementById && document.createTextNode && document.getElementById('finder')) {
    // add the class domenabled to the body
    cssjs('add',document.body,'domenabled');
}
</script>
```

UPDATE 2:

This isn't right. The `domenabled` class isn't what causes things to be hidden. There's a loop in `finder.js` with the comment:

```
// loop through all lists inside finder, position and hide them 
// by applying the class hidden
```

and this is what hides all those elements. And none of this runs until after the page is loaded.

I don't know about your CSS dropdowns, but maybe Modernizr can be of help there.

Comment: sorry - dumb question - do i just add this to my html, or do i add more??   <script type="text/javascript">   
// Check if the browser supports DOM, and start the script if it does.
if(document.getElementById && document.createTextNode)
{window.onload=ul2finder;}
</script>

Comment: No, the whole point is to do it BEFORE the onload handler runs. Anything put in `window.onload` won't run until everything has been loaded and rendered. See my update.

Comment: I finally had a chance to work on this again - did what you suggested and it still isn't helping.  Any additional suggestions??  I'm still very new to building websites so I apologize if I have misunderstood something you told me to do... (I reloaded the site in the same location).  thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sorry, there are two problems with my suggestion. 1. It runs before the DOM is loaded, so getElementById('finder') doesn't find anything, so you need to remove that part of the `if`. 2. `cssjs` is an internal function in `ul2finder`, so it can't be called from here; change that to `document.body.className+=' domenabled';`.

Comment: But I think I misread the finder.js code earlier. I don't think you can solve this without some significant rewrite to finder.js; complain to the author.

Comment: thanks anyway!  do you know of any code/javascript that will allow me to accomplish the same kind of layout the finder.js gives me?? i had a difficult time finding the 'finder.js' as it was...